# existence of both $f\cdot h$ and $\frac{f}h$

Tags: limits, proof-verification

I reviewed old material and I saw the proof that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ then it is continuous at $a$:$$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\\\implies f(a+h)-f(a)=f'(a)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}h=\lim_{h\to0}hf'(a)=0\\\implies f(a+h)=f(a)$$

so i had an idea, show that there is no function $f(x,h)$ that both $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,h)}h$ and $\lim\limits_{h\to0}{f(x,h)}h$ exist

Lemma 1:$$\text{let's $f(x,h)$ be continuous, then: }\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,h)}{h}=A\implies \lim_{h\to0}f(x,h)=0\\\because \lim_{h\to0}f(x,h)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h}{h}f(x,h)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,h)}{h}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,h)}{h}\lim_{h\to0}h=A\cdot0=0$$

lemma 2:
$$\text{let's $f(x,t)$ be continuous, then: }\lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}f(x,t)t=B,B\ne0\implies\left|\lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}f(x,t)\right|\longrightarrow\infty\\\because\lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}t{f\left(x,t\right)}=B,B\ne0\\\implies \lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}f\left(x,t\right)=\lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}\frac{t}{t}f\left(x,t\right)=\lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}\frac{tf\left(x,t\right)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}\frac{B}t\\\implies\left|\lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}f\left(x,t\right)\right|\longrightarrow\infty$$

assume $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x,h)}h$ exist then by lemma 1 I have $\lim\limits_{h\to0}{f(x,h)}=0$ so by lemma 2 I know $\lim\limits_{h\to0}h{f(x,h)}$ doesn't exist.

Am I right? If not where do I have mistake?

Comment: you can not apply Lemma 2 to $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x,h)=0$ because $B=0$.

Comment: and if i do it the opposite way? if $h\cdot f$ exist then $f(x,h)$ doesn't  and thus $\frac{f}h$ also doesn't  exist?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand wha you say... Anyway, any function of the form $g(h) =ah^n$ for some $a\in \Bbb R$ and $n\geq 1$ is so that both limits $\lim_{h\to 0}hg(h)$ and $\lim_{h\to 0}g(h)/h$. Furthermore you can add such functions.

Comment: Note that in your proof of Lemma 2, $\lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}\frac{tf\left(x,t\right)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0^{\pm}}\frac{B}t$ is a wrong step.